# How can I make A Pipeline Using Border In CSS

Tags: html, css

Maybe from the title above some of you will become confused, But it exactly as the title said, I want to make this **pipeline design using CSS**, I think I can achieve it using `border` but how can I add the **round bullet** like in the image below?

[image: The pipeline with blue color that I want to make]

to make it easier, my **layout** will look like this:

1. **First row** : Image 1 & text
2. **second row** : Text & Image 2
3. **Third row** : Image 3 & text
4. **fourth row** : Image 4

so this is **some question I want to ask**:

1. Can I make this kind of line using the border?
2. How can I make the line stop in the middle like before the Image 4?
3. How can I make the bullet in the middle of the line that will match the line even when we check it in some device (exclude the mobile view around 576px)?

Can someone help me with this problem? for the **first question**, I think we can use

```
1. First Row :
border-right: solid 1px blue;
border-bottom : solid 1px blue;
border-bottom-right-radius : 10px;

2. second Row :
border-left: solid 1px blue;
border-bottom : solid 1px blue;
border-bottom-left-radius : 10px;

3. Third Row :
border-right: solid 1px blue;
border-bottom : solid 1px blue;
border-bottom-right-radius : 10px;

4. Fourth Row : 
border-left: solid 1px blue;
border-bottom : solid 1px blue;
border-bottom-left-radius : 10px;
width: 50% (?)
```

**Edit 1**
for question one currently I make this CSS code like this:

```
#first-row-left{
    border-left: solid 3px blue;
    border-bottom: solid 3px blue;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px
}

#first-row-right{
    border-bottom: solid 3px blue;
}

#second-row-left{
    border-bottom: solid 3px blue;

}

#second-row-right{
    border-right: solid 3px blue;
    border-bottom: solid 3px blue;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px
}

#third-row-left{
    border-left: solid 3px blue;
    border-bottom: solid 3px blue;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px

}
```

and it looks like this

[image: This is my current progress when using border]

As you can see there is **slight miss in before the pipeline change the row like from first to second row**

**Edit 2** I already make a fiddle for this, you can try it in here:

[Click here to see the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RFTaurus/10g4t8sb/)

**Edit 3**
Based on @Alexwc_ , I tried to change his code into CSS intead of SCSS, but it seems I miss something in here

SCSS from @Alexwc_ after I convert it to CSS:

this is the fiddle I made : [Check in here](https://jsfiddle.net/RFTaurus/10g4t8sb/26/)

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried? @Rakish Frisky

Comment: @MeghnaBhuptani Thankyou for your response, I already edit my thread and uploaded my progress

Comment: Can you please share the code in codepen or jsfiddle? @Rakish Frisky

Comment: @MeghnaBhuptani I already edit my thread, and put the fiddle in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one method. Perhaps not the cleanest, and it hasn't been adapted for mobile.

[Here is a pen of the work using SCSS.](https://codepen.io/alexwc_/full/vYEOBmK)

[Here is a pen of the work using CSS.](https://codepen.io/alexwc_/full/RwNPpGd) (Please note that I converted SCSS to CSS using [this tool](https://www.sassmeister.com/))

**CAVEATS:**

1. this was not put into a SO snippet because (for whatever reason) it doesn't display correctly.
2. I've tested only on Mac OS Chrome/Chrome Canary/FF/FFDE/Safari
3. On the CodePen I used SCSS
4. My CSS/SCSS/variables may cause some snickering as I'm no pro at it, and it feels a little hacky... but perhaps other edge-ish cases may cause the same feeling.
5. I did not see that you had posted your own markup while I was writing this out. Apologies for that.
6. The bullets can be edited to however you like, I figured the bullet styles weren't the real issue here.

CSS:

```
:root {
    --width: 5px;
    --border-radius: calc(var(--width) * 2);
    --button-width: 30px;
    --button-left-pos: -12.5px;
}

.row {
    margin: 0 20px;
}

img {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.one, .two, .three, .four {
    position: relative;
}
.one::before, .one::after, .two::before, .two::after, .three::before, .three::after, .four::before, .four::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--button-width);
    left: var(--button-left-pos);
    content: "";
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
.one::after, .two::after, .three::after, .four::after {
    width: calc( var(--button-width) / 2 );
    height: calc( var(--button-width) / 2 );
    background: red;
    top: calc(var(--button-width) + var(--button-width) / 4 );
    left: -5px;
}

.two::before, .two::after {
    right: var(--button-left-pos);
    left: initial;
}
.two::after {
    right: -5px;
}

.one::after {
    width: calc( var(--button-width) / 2 );
    height: calc( var(--button-width) / 2 );
    background: red;
    top: calc(var(--button-width) + var(--button-width) / 4 );
}

.row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "left right";
    position: relative;
}
.row:last-child {
    grid-template-areas: "border ..." "full full";
}
.row .left, .row .right {
    padding: var(--button-width);
}

.one .left {
    padding-top: 0;
    border-left: var(--width) solid;
    border-bottom: var(--width) solid;
    border-bottom-left-radius: var(--width);
}

.two {
    top: calc(var(--width) * -1);
}
.two .right {
    border-right: var(--width) solid;
    border-top: var(--width) solid;
    border-top-right-radius: var(--width);
    border-bottom-right-radius: var(--width);
    border-bottom: var(--width) solid;
}

.three {
    top: calc(var(--width) * -2);
}
.three .left {
    border-left: var(--width) solid;
    border-top: var(--width) solid;
    border-top-left-radius: var(--width);
    border-bottom-left-radius: var(--width);
}

.four {
    top: calc(var(--width) * -3);
}
.four::before, .four::after {
    top: 85px;
}
.four::before {
    left: calc(50% - 17.5px);
}
.four::after {
    top: 92.5px;
    left: calc(50% - 10.5px);
}
.four .border {
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    border-right: var(--width) solid;
    border-top-right-radius: var(--width);
    position: relative;
}
.four .border::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: var(--width);
    background: black;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(100% + var(--width));
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    border-bottom-left-radius: var(--width);
    border-top-right-radius: var(--width);
}

.border {
    grid-area: border;
}

.full-width {
    grid-area: full;
    justify-self: center;
}

.left {
    grid-area: left;
}

.right {
    grid-area: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row one">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x250" alt="">

    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- one -->
  <div class="row two">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x250" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- two -->
  <div class="row three">
    <div class="left">

      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x250" alt="">

    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- three -->
  <div class="row four">
    <div class="border border-top"></div>
    <div class="full-width">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x500" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <!-- four -->
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, I tried your code and it looks exactly like I want, but when I tried to convert it to CSS the layout change, can you point it where I do it wrong? I already add a new fiddle based on your SCSS that I convert to CSS

Comment: @RakishFrisky use the CSS from the answer. It works (in a pen, and local file) on my end

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, after I tweak your answer a little bit to fit my desain properly, your solution is the most near from what I expected, at first I'm seriously lost when see `:root` and `var` in CSS but when I search it, it turns a pseudoelement for CSS, once again thankyou for the new knowledge ^.^

Answer (score 3):

You may consider using SVG. Following code is a sample code to draw path and circle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="400" width="450">
<path id="lineAB" d="M 100 350 l 150 -300" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <path id="lineBC" d="M 250 50 l 150 300" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 100 350 q 150 -300 300 0" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="black">
    <circle id="pointA" cx="100" cy="350" r="3" />
    <circle id="pointB" cx="250" cy="50" r="3" />
    <circle id="pointC" cx="400" cy="350" r="3" />
  </g>
  <g font-size="30" font-family="sans-serif" fill="black" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle">
    <text x="100" y="350" dx="-30">A</text>
    <text x="250" y="50" dy="-10">B</text>
    <text x="400" y="350" dx="30">C</text>
  </g>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but if we using svg, doesn't it means we must call it like an image, using background-image, or border-image?

Comment: Not necessarily. It is like an HTML tag only. SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) is an XML-based vector image format for two-dimensional graphics with support for interactivity and animation. For drawing images, it uses simple geometrical figures (lines, circle, polygon, etc.). It is some what like canvas element in HTML5 but not exactly canvas. Even most javascript based interactive maps are using SVG.

Comment: Please refer link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg

Comment: Thankyou for the reference, I think I'll try to read the reference first

Answer (score 2):

```
`#first-row-left:before
{
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 50%;
 left: 0;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 z-index: 3;
 top: 25px;
}`
```

try something like this...

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, I try your code but it seems nothing change

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `border-image` property to draw a custom `svg` for your border. Have a look at [this article](https://dev.to/jackharner/using-svg-as-a-border-with-css-57ib) to see an example.

Answer (score 0):

The Round bullet can be done with an external div like

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='bullet'></div>
    </body>
</html>

#bullet{
    background-color:#fff310;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:0.1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, I tried your code, and it can solve the problem number two. but how can I attach the bullet in the pipe line?